# How to write Query in Yii

Tags: yii

how to write this in yii

```
SELECT schedule.checkin, schedule.checkout, schedule.days, 
employee.firstname, employee.lastname, week.start_date, week.end_date
FROM schedule
INNER JOIN employee_schedule
ON schedule.id=employee_schedule.sched_id
INNER JOIN employee
ON employee.id=employee_schedule.emp_id
INNER JOIN week
ON week.id=employee_schedule.week_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use something like:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select * from post')->queryAll();
```

to get your data. Though i would like to point out that if in future you try to switch from mySQL to some other database whose query syntax is different then you must try the other answer by @kumar_v as it will still work there and this one might not.

Comment: thanks this help me a lot, but is it the only way that I can do Joining in Yii?? thank you very much @Rahul

Comment: joining can be done in many ways... check out this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJoinQuery#createCommand-detail) but befor going to that also see if you can get your data using relations in CModel class

Answer (score 2):

Try it yourself.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

for example:

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('id, username, profile')
->from('tbl_user u')
->join('tbl_profile p', 'u.id=p.user_id')
->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
->queryRow();
```

You can  build your query like this.

Comment: I dont know how to write the syntax in 3 tables

Comment: refer this url: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22919-two-joins-in-query-builder/

$data= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select()
->from('items i')
->join('sub_categories sc', 'sc.id = i.sub_category_id')
->join('categories c','c.id = sc.main_category_id');


Read full forum.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("your query")->queryScalar();
```

can try this too